# How can one debug the Chrome extension "options" page using the new OptionsV2 method?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2 tells me that I should be using `options_ui` in my manifest, rather than `options_page`, and recommends I start upgrading immediately.

However, I can't find any way to actually debug the script run by my options page when I use `options_ui`—the Options popup is in an  tag, and the developer tools don't show me the source, or even the HTML content.

For now, I just comment out `options_ui` and let `options_page` take effect when I need to debug. I'm guessing that setting `"options_ui": {"open_in_tab": true,...}` would have the same effect, but it would be really nice to figure out how to actually debug the script when it's running the new way.

Comment: Why should you get to use options in a tab when you don't let your users?

Comment: I can right click in the option dialog and "inspect element".  That brings up the developer tools on the elements tab.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Teepeemm Sorry, clearly a case of not seeing the forest for the trees. That works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @Auspex by the way with this approach are you **also** facing lag un loading of otions page ?

Comment: @exexzian I haven't noticed any lag.

Comment: I am not able to debug the options dialog by right-clicking the dialog and selecting "inspect element".  When I do this, the same dev console appears as when entering <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>, and it has selected the <extensions-options-dialog> in the Elements tab.  But I cannot inspect any javascript, I see no window.alert, I see no console.log output in the Console tab.  I'm confused why this is said to have worked.  Maybe Chrome changed.  The only technique that works for me is to open in a new tab.

Comment: @CarlG I'm afraid I haven't done any Chrome extension development in years  but a quick look into the options page that triggered this question in 2015 still shows that I'm able to do all normal debugging just as long as I bring up the options page and right-click somewhere in it to "Inspect element"

Comment: By "bring up the options page" you mean the options dialog?  The one that overlays the extension details? https://imgur.com/a/2MzSwli  Hmm, if that's the case then I don't know what I am doing wrong.  Thanks for checking anyway.

Comment: @CarlG Yes, that's the one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Auspex,

Teepeemm's comment is correct.

Other way, you can launch your options page from other tab using its full URL
like,

```
chrome-extension://{your extension id here}/{your options page path here, from the extension root}
```

e.g. say my extension id aaabbbcccdddeeefffggg, and say, my options page is located (from extension root) at app/html/options.html; then i can load up below URL in a new tab ---

```
chrome-extension://aaabbbcccdddeeefffggg/app/html/options.html
```

Now here, in this tab; you can do your regular debugging around HTML and javascript.

I hope this suffices your debugging requirement for 'new options UI' for chrome.

Comment: Downvoting: "can't debug from there" is incorrect. Please take that part out of the answer, I'll be happy to reverse my vote then.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Teepeemm's comment is correct, too. You can inspect the shown options dialog and then inspect options JS. And I guess, that would be the easiest way to debug. Correcting my opinion.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Teepeemm's comment is correct.

It's as simple as right-clicking inside the options page modal and selecting "Inspect element" - it will open the correct Dev Tools.

Comment: This doesn't work when I have the `debugger;` keyword in my options page script during page-load, unfortunately. The Dev Tools simply doesn't hit the breakpoint.